# QGIS 3.4.4 Attribute table expression not working anymore

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-3

After uptdating Qgis to 3.4.4 the following expression doesn't working anymore:

```
"art" LIKE '%'  || attribute ( @atlas_feature , 'artere')  || '%'
```

We're using it in the printcomposer, specifically on an attribute table.
It was used to display lines with `art` value containing the same value as the layer we're using to generate the atlas, which always has the column `artere`.

On previous version, it was working. Not anymore.

Did we do something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. What was your previous QGis-version? And how exactly do you use this expression?

Comment: Thanks
My previous version was 3.2
I was using this expression in a print composer.
We are using an atlas. The atlas is set up on a layer. This layer have a colum named "artere".
the expression I posetd is used in the print composer on a attribute table.
The objective is to display every line of this layer containing the same value as the "artere" in his "art" colum.
A minor detail, the "art" colum of the attribute table can contain something like this : 01 02 05

When the composer map show the line '05', we want the attribute table to display every line containint '05' it "art" colum

Comment: After checking it out, seems `attribute(@atlas_feature, 'field')` doesn't return the field values. That's weird. Didn't test in 3.2, but I tried in 2.18 and the function returns the field values correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this was/is [a bug](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21078), reported in the issue tracker, that is already solved and should get corrected in the next release:

> Within the layout composer, the 'filter with' feature on attribute tables no longer works for with @... variables.
>   I have tested this with @layout_name, @atlas_pagename, @atlas_featureid, @project_crs and @project_author variables but assume it doesn't work with any of them.

If it's critical, maybe revert to your last working version until it gets released?

Comment: So many thanks, even if unsolved at least I know we didn't do something wrong.
It was a hell to set this up. Think we'll roll back to a previous version.

I still got one question, what is the lastest qgis version where the 'filter with" feature on attribute tales still work ?

Comment: @CBATS This I have no idea unfortunately.

Comment: Don't worry, we'll stick to previous working installed qgis version and wait...