# QGIS 3.4.5 Attribute table expression in print composer not working

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer, feature-filter

I just upgraded from QGIS 2.18 to the latest stable release (3.4.5).

I am trying to filter an attribute table added to a layout by using @atlas_pagename and I can see there is a match in the expression builder but my table stays blank as if it can't find a match.

This might be the same issue as in this thread (the same problem in 3.4.4) :
[QGIS 3.4.4 Attribute table expression not working anymore](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310140/qgis-3-4-4-attribute-table-expression-not-working-anymore) but on the bug tracker this issue has been closed and reportedly it was solved and corrected for the next release.

Can anyone confirm it's still broken in 3.4.5? I don't know how to report/reopen bugs but will happily report it if anyone can tell me how.